# Encoding from 1252 to Unicode .NET equivalent in java

Tags: java, .net, unicode, encoding, windows-1252

I have the request to port a .NET web service to java. I need to find the equivalent java code for this piece of code written in .NET:

```
byte[] b = ... // Some file binary data.
byte[] encoded = System.Text.Encoding.Convert(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252), System.Text.Encoding.Unicode, b);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
byte[] b = ...
byte[] encoded = new String(b, "Cp1252").getBytes("UTF-16");
```

Comment: Or UTF-8, for typical use cases.

Comment: Nicola explicitly asked for System.Text.Encoding.Unicode, which is UTF-16.

Comment: Yes, I tried with new String(b, "Cp1252").getBytes("UTF-16LE"); but unfortunately it doesn't work. The byte[] contains a PDF file, what I can see is that the bytes converted from .NET and the ones from java are the same at the beginning of the file (%PDF...) but as soon as the binary part of the file begins a lot of bytes are diffent.

Comment: @Nicola: You cannot do character set conversions on arbitrary binary data (like a PDF document). It will only work if b contains Cp1252-encoded text.

Comment: @jarnbjo: I think you are right, probably I'm doing it wrong, I'll ask a new question to explain in detail what I'm trying to achieve. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look on the [List of Supported Encoding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html) in java. Cp1252 encoding in java is theequivalent encoding of windows 1252.